# Devise Controller Test undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When I write my test like this, **it works**:

```
require 'test_helper'

class HomeControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  test "signed in" do
      sign_in users(:default)
      get :show, params: { id: 33 }
      assert_redirected_to user_session_path
  end
end
```

However when I change the style of my test class a little bit with `describe`:

```
require 'test_helper'

describe HomeController do
  include Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers

  describe "signed in" do
    it "works" do
      sign_in users(:default)
      get :show, params: { id: 33 }
      assert_redirected_to user_session_path
    end
  end
end
```

Then I get the following error:

```
undefined method `env' for nil:NilClass
```

I guess that's because of `Devise::Test::ControllerHelpers` and because `describe HomeController` is not anymore `ActionController::TestCase`.

**How would you try to solve this problem? What could I try?** Thanks